# is .snk containing both private key and public key?

Tags: c#, .net

As title, want to know if both keys are inside 1 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a key pair:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy.aspx